# Spring MVC getJdbcTemplate insert em Oracle retornar valor de coluna

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, jdbc

Tenho um projeto em Spring MVC, estou a usar o `getJdbcTemplate` para fazer insert's.

Só que não insiro a primary key no Oracle a partir de uma sequencia e preciso desse valor para voltar a inserir em outra tabela onde esse valor é chave estrangeira.

Por exemplo:

```
insert into tableS(SEQ, dateX, ab, flag) values(SEQ_table.nextval, ?, ?, 'N')
```

E estou a usar o `getJdbcTemplate` para inserir a partir do Spring, só que preciso do valor do SEQ do lado do java para inserir na tabela que se segue com o valor em chave estrangeira.

```
getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(INSERT_TABLE, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

  public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                String valor= info.getvalues().get(i);
                ps.setString(1, valor.geta());
                ps.setLong(2, valor.getb());
            }

            public int getBatchSize() {
                return  info.getvalues().size();
            }
});
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver este problema?

Comment: Alguma restrição em relação ao uso do JPA?

Comment: gostava não ter que alterar a estrutura do projecto , devido ao tempo, mas com JPA consigo obter o valor inserido ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a classe JdbcTemplate você deverá fazer assim:

```
final String INSERT_SQL = "insert into my_test (name) values(?)";
final String name = "Rob";

KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps =
                connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL, new String[] {"id"}); // Esse informa ao Driver JDBC as chaves que serão geradas
            ps.setString(1, name);
            return ps;
        }
    },
    keyHolder);

// keyHolder.getKey() - Aqui você obtem a chave ("id") gerada
```

Outra forma de obter durante uma insersão é utilizando a classse: SimpleJdbcInsert

```
public class JdbcActorDao implements ActorDao {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcInsert insertActor;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        this.insertActor =
                new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
                        .withTableName("t_actor")
                        .usingColumns("first_name", "last_name")
                        .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id"); // Informa quais a chaves serão geradas.
    }

    public void add(Actor actor) {
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        parameters.put("first_name", actor.getFirstName());
        parameters.put("last_name", actor.getLastName());
        Number newId = insertActor.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);
        actor.setId(newId.longValue()); // Obtem a chave gerada.
    }
}
```

Não tem um opção para fazer isso em lote como no seu exemplo.